# re-entrency of interrupts in Linux

Tags: linux, kernel, interrupt

I was reading "Linux device drivers, 3rd edition" and don't completely
understand a part describing interrupt handlers. I would like to clarify:

- are the interrupt handlers in Linux nonpreemptible?
- are the interrupt handlers in Linux non-reentrant?

I believe I understand the model of Top/Bottom halves quite well, and
according to it the interrupts are disabled for as long as the TopHalf
is being executed, thus the handler can't be re-entered, am I right?

But what about high priority interrupts? Are they supported by vanilla Linux or
specific real-time extensions only? What happens if a low priority interrupt
is interrupted by high priority one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Linux kernel is reentrant (like all UNIX ones), which simply means that multiple processes can be executed by the CPU. He doesn't have to wait till a disk access read is handled by the deadly slow HDD controller, the CPU can process some other stuff until the disk access is finished (which itself will trigger an interrupt if so).

Generally, an interrupt can be interrupted by an other interrupt (preemption), that's called 'Nested Execution'. Depending on the architecture, there are still some critical functions which have to run without interruption (non-preemptive) by completely disabling interrupts. On x86, these are some time relevant functions (`time.c`, `hpet.c`) and some `xen` stuff.

There are only two priority levels concerning interrupts: 'enable all interrupts' or 'disable all interrupts', so I guess your "high priority interrupt" is the second one. This is the only behavior the Linux kernel knows concerning interrupt priorities and has nothing to do with real-time extensions.

If an interruptible interrupt (your "low priority interrupt") gets interrupted by an other interrupt ("high" or "low"), the kernel saves the old execution code of the interrupted interrupt and starts to process the new interrupt. This "nesting" can happen multiple times and thus can create multiple levels of interrupted interrupts. Afterwards, the kernel reloads the saved code from the old interrupt and tries to finish the old one.

Comment: "Generally, an interrupt can be interrupted by an other interrupt (preemption), that's called 'Nested Execution'. " - this has been true in the past, but isn't anymore since 2.6.35 / 2010: see https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit and /e58aa3d2d0cc01ad8d6f7f640a0670433f794922 https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/b738a50a202639614c98b5763b01bf9201779e50 (see also https://linux-kernel-labs.github.io/refs/heads/master/lectures/interrupts.html#nested-interrupts-and-exceptions)

Answer (score 1):

Nonpreemptible means that those handlers cannot be interrupted by another interrupt.

For non-preemtible handlers, reentrance is a non issue since you cannot interrupt them in the first place.

As to what the kernel does, just check wag's answer, I can't comment like he does on this topic.

Comment: Actually, according to http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-10-sect-2.shtml only `fast interrupts (those that were requested with the SA_INTERRUPT flag) are executed with all other interrupts disabled on the current processor`

Comment: @Justin: you're right of course, I made my comment more general - my point was theoretical: it aimed to address the meaning of nonpreemtible and reentrance.